# AWS How to deploy my internet site created with Typescript on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have create a website using VS Code in NodeJS with typescript language.

Now I want to try to deploy it on AWS. I read so many things about EC2 , Cloud9 , Elastic Beanstalk, etc...

So I'm totally lost about what to use to deploy my website.
Honestly I'm a programmer, not a site manager or sysops.

Right Now I create an EC2 instances. One with a Key name and One with no key Name.

In the Elastic Beanstalk, I have a button Upload and Deploy.

Can someone send me the way to create my project as a valid package to upload and deploy it ?

I never deploy a website. (Normally it was the sysops at the job). So I don't know what to do to have a correct distributing package.

Does I need to create both EC2 and Beanstalk ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you go with ElasticBeanstalk, it will take care of creating the EC2 instances for your.

It actually takes care of creating EC2 instance, DB, loadbalancers, CloudWatch trails and many more. This is pretty much what it does, bundles multiple AWS services and offers on panel of administration.

To get started with EB you should install the [eb cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html).

Then you should:

- go to your directory and run [eb init application-name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html). You'll start a wizard from eb cli asking you in which region you want to deploy, what kind of db and so on
- after that your need to run [eb create envname](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html) to create a new env for your newly create application.
- at this point you should head to the EB aws panel and configure the `start` command for your app, it usually is something like this `npm run prod`
- because you're using TS there are a few steps you need to do before being able to deploy. You should run `npm run build`, or whatever command you have for transpiling from TS to JS. You'll be deploying compiled scripts and not your source code.
- now you are ready to deploy, you can run `eb deploy`, as this is your only env it should work, when you have multiple envs you can do `eb deploy envname`. For getting a list of all envs you can run `eb list`

There are quite a few steps to take care before deploying and any of them can cause multiple issues.

Comment: Maybe it's the best way, but like I said I hate link explanation, that is very UNCLEAR for me. I made all the steps. Now I'm stuck in the EB Create envname. Honestly it's not very clear. I get an error :  Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
Could not push code to the CodeCommit repository:
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/origin/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: I never used CodeCommit, when running eb init, set use CodeCommit to no

Comment: Look. I ask someone to give me a STEP by STEP instructions to deploy my Typescript site made under VS CODE on AWS.  In your description, you linked me 3 times on AWS page about eb cli, eb init, etc.. Like I said these pages doesn't help me. I want a CLEAR example step by step on how to do it. AWS page has too many things. As you see I'm in code commit, now you said to not use that. AWS has too many products to be clear. Can someone writes a clear step by step instructions to made it. Each steph on how to create a client . Now I have 3 or 4 users , keys, I'm totally LOST. Thanks for an help.

Answer (score 0):

If your website contains only static pages you can use Amazon S3 to deploy your website.
You can put your build files in S3 bucket directly and enable static web hosting. 
This will allow anyone to access your website from a url globally, for this you have to make your bucket public also.
Instead you can also use cloudfront here to keep your bucket private but allowing access to bucket through cloudfront url.
You can refer to below links for hosting website through s3.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/